# http web request login fails - but username and password are correct

Tags: vb.net, authentication, visual-studio-2015, httpwebrequest, http-authentication

This is the code im using to sign it into website with http web request
something is going wrong and it's not my username and password.  I'm using http live headers to get information about the post message.  When I try the code it give me a page as if it was the wrong username or password.

```
    Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim logincookie As CookieContainer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim postdata As String = "username=myusername%40gmail.com&token=fec2af73418281b566fe86d6fc02980e&perslogin=Y&password=mypassword%40&tprefs1=&tprefs2=9yUXLS7QDJXD.1oiOS1.51CcYO"
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postdata)

        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://secure.thewebsite.com/secure_login.html?ver=2&loc=en_US&r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thewebsite.com%2Fhome.html%3Fjli%3D1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thewebsite.com"), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        postReq.Referer = "https://secure.thewebsite.com/secure_login.html?ver=2&loc=en_US&r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thewebsite.com%2Fhome.html%3Fjli%3D1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thewebsite.com"
        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
        logincookie = tempCookies
        Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

        Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
        RichTextBox1.Text = thepage

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = RichTextBox1.Text
    End Sub
End class
```

This is the response I get:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.parent.location.href ="https://secure.thewebsite.com/register.html?display=login";
        </script>
     </head>
     <body >
     </body>
</html>
```

Any idea what is going wrong make the login fail?

Comment: I would do some research on how to debug vb.net HttpWebRequest. I am not that familiar with vb.net but in my other dealings with trying to log into web forms there is usually an option to DEBUG the connection, i.e., have it dump out what it is sending/recieving to/from the server. I think their may be some third party tools for intercepting web requests, however, being that it is over HTTPS you are better off figuring out how to get the HttpWebRequest to "show its stuff," in a manner of speaking. Also, use Firefox, Developer Tools > Network Tab, login, then look for potential differences.

Comment: Automating logins to a website is always a challenge, as each may have its own quirks and protections against exactly what you're trying to do. You may have to fetch the page first with a `CookieContainer` and return the cookies back through your post, and in-page tokens / hidden fields may be different each time you fetch the page and you'll have to return all of those. Hidden fields may change names per request and/or be added through javascript callbacks as additional baffles against brute force bots. There's little chance we could help you with this.